# Get data from specific columns in table when row checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get from specific table columns in a row. All data should be pushed into an array.
I should take data from each checked row from different columns (1,3,4). Column #4 contains drop-down option and it should take only selected value.
I am having a hard time getting this function to work, it works if I have only one column. I am facing trouble when I am retrieving data from , it retrieves all data from option values, I should get only selected value.

```js
function getData() {

  // Enumerate over each checked checkbox
  $('input:checked').each(function() {
    var row = [];

    $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(5)').each(function() {

      row.push($(this).text());

    });

    // Add this row to our list of rows
    rows.push(row);

    //debugger;
  });
  console.log(row);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="1"></td>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>
      <select id="country">
        <option value='1'>Germany</option>
        <option value='2'>England</option>
        <option value='3'>Croatia</option>
        <option value='4'>USA</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="2"></td>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>
      <select id="country">
        <option value='1'>Germany</option>
        <option value='2'>England</option>
        <option value='3'>Croatia</option>
        <option value='4'>USA</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="3"></td>
    <td>Amanda</td>
    <td>Jac</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>
      <select id="country">
        <option value='1'>Germany</option>
        <option value='2'>England</option>
        <option value='3'>Croatia</option>
        <option value='4'>USA</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="getData()">Submit</button>
```

Function displays only data from one column. If I add .'td:eg(6)' I got empty array

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Your javascript is not enough to run the code and understand what is going wrong.

Comment: @Oram I updated code

Comment: @Bruno you want array of object containing all data in a row or just the selected dropdown value?

Comment: @MohanRajput I want an array containing data from columns 1, 3 and 4 (Firstname, Age,Country) which is selected dropdown value

Answer (score 3):

@Bruno your case is little different and to get the desired result I have updated your code for button click event & it is as follow.

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    var rows = [];

$('input:checked').each(function() {
    var row = $(this).parent().parent();
    
    var data = {};
        $(row).find("td").each(function(i,obj){
            if(i == 1){
                data.name = $(this).text();
        }
        else if(i == 3){
                data.age = $(this).text();
        }
        else if(i == 4){
                data.country = $(this).find("select").val();
        }
    })
            
    rows.push(data);
  })
  console.log(rows);
})
```

And before implementing it to your code you can play it in here at [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/76src4uy/2/).

In fiddle demo open console [F12] you can see your list of selected row value in an array.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here i try your result to get select row dropdwun value.

```js
function getData(){
var rows=[];

    // Enumerate over each checked checkbox
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        var row = [];

       var cnty= $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(5)').children('select').val();
    var fname=$(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
    var lname=$(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
    var age=$(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(4)').text();
    var vals=[fname ,lname, age, cnty];
            row.push(vals);



        // Add this row to our list of rows
        rows.push(row);

        //debugger;
    });
    console.log(rows);

}
```

```html
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="1"></td>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>20</td>
    <td>
      <select id="country">
        <option value='1'>Germany</option>
        <option value='2'>England</option>
        <option value='3'>Croatia</option>
        <option value='4'>USA</option>
      </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="2"></td>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>14</td>
    <td>
      <select id="country">
        <option value='1'>Germany</option>
        <option value='2'>England</option>
        <option value='3'>Croatia</option>
        <option value='4'>USA</option>
      </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="3"></td>
    <td>Amanda</td>
    <td>Jac</td> 
    <td>14</td>
    <td>
      <select id="country">
        <option value='1'>Germany</option>
        <option value='2'>England</option>
        <option value='3'>Croatia</option>
        <option value='4'>USA</option>
      </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <button type="button" onclick="getData()">Submit</button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, I need an array containing data from columns 1, 3 and 4 (Firstname, Age,Country) which is selected dropdown value. Your solution does not work well it does not give any data.

Comment: i edit the above code.
please check if it is helpful for you.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could have all the selected values on button click. Just iterate over all `tr` and find `select` inside and get the `value` .

```js
function getData(){
  $("tr").each(function() {
     if($(this).find("select")){
      console.log($(this).find("select").val())
     } 
   });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="1"></td>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>20</td>
    <td>
      <select class="select-cls" id="country">
        <option value='1'>Germany</option>
        <option value='2'>England</option>
        <option value='3'>Croatia</option>
        <option value='4'>USA</option>
      </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="2"></td>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>14</td>
    <td>
      <select  id="country">
        <option value='1'>Germany</option>
        <option value='2'>England</option>
        <option value='3'>Croatia</option>
        <option value='4'>USA</option>
      </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="3"></td>
    <td>Amanda</td>
    <td>Jac</td> 
    <td>14</td>
    <td>
      <select id="country">
        <option value='1'>Germany</option>
        <option value='2'>England</option>
        <option value='3'>Croatia</option>
        <option value='4'>USA</option>
      </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <button type="button" onclick="getData()">Submit</button>
```